# How to use custom sprite icon for kendo ui treeview in angular js?

Tags: css, angularjs, kendo-treeview

I use [kendo ui treeview in angular js](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/angular).

```html
<div id="treeview">
    <div class="demo-section k-content">
        <div class="box-col">
            <h4>TreeView</h4>
            <div kendo-tree-view="tree"
                k-data-source="treeData"
                k-options="options"
                <%-- k-checkboxes="{'checkChildren': true, 'template': checkboxTemplate }"--%>
                k-on-change="selectedItem = dataItem">
                <span k-template>{{dataItem.text}}
                    <button class='k-button' type="button" ng-click='clickOnTree(dataItem)'>Select</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-col" ng-show="selectedItem">
            <h4>Selected: {{selectedItem.text}}</h4>
            <button type="button" class="k-button" ng-click="addAfter(selectedItem)">Add item below</button>
            <button type="button" class="k-button" ng-click="addBelow(selectedItem)">Add child item</button>
            <button type="button" class="k-button" ng-click="remove(selectedItem)">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want use sprite icon for it.I don't want use background-position.I want set background image to it directly.for example like this below css code:

```css
<style>
 #treeview .k-sprite {
           
        }

        .cross {
            background-image: url("mypath/mypic.png");
        }

        
</style>
```

```js
    $scope.treeData = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
        data: [
              {
                  text: "item1", spriteCssClass: "cross"
              },
             
              { text: "item2", spriteCssClass: "otherclass" }
        ]
       
    });
```

How can I do it?